# Find the value of $\sin(x + y)$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\sin x = \dfrac13$ and $\sec y = \dfrac54$, where $x$ and $y$ lie between $0$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then evaluate the expression,

$\sin (x + y)$

The answer is $\dfrac{1}{15}\big(4 + 6 \sqrt 2)$. Since the answer is in this form I assume I don't use a calculator. I don't even know where to begin. What procedure would I use for a problem like this? Am I supposed to actually figure out the values of x and y, or is that impossible and the answer is derived another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given is, $\sin x = \dfrac13$ and $\cos y = \dfrac45$,

We know that,

$\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ and $\sin y=\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}$,

$\therefore \cos x=\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{3}$ and $\sin y=\dfrac{3}{5}$

Using, $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$

$\sin(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{5}+\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{3}{5}=\dfrac{4}{15}+\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{5}=\dfrac{1}{15}\big(4 + 6 \sqrt 2)$

Comment: i completely forgot about the $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$ part, makes sense, thanks

Comment: @ludragon You're welcome! I'm glad I could help :)